# Copy data to excel with VBA from a website using Classname

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get information from a website but I cannot get any data.
https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/AAPL/
 I have the same problem as in this post [R rvest retrieve empty table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684947/r-rvest-retrieve-empty-table)
How can I do it in VBA? I found this code on the internet, I modified it but it does not get data, and the information appears in a window instead of pasting it in the spreadsheet.
If you directly export the whole table it would be great, otherwise I would have to copy cell by cell.
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Get_Web_Data()
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant
' Website to go to.
website = "https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/AAPL/"
' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False
' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send
' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response
' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
price = html.getElementsByClassName("book-viewer__ask book-viewer__ask-shares").Item(2).innerText
' Output the price into a message box.
MsgBox price
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think using `HTMLDocument` will work. The page your viewing has no data on initially, it is loaded in by javascript. I don't think `HTMLDocument` will execute javascript, so no data gets loaded. Try using `InternetExplorer` instead of XMLHTTP

Comment: I tried this one but I dont get the numbers, just the names  http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/default.php

Comment: I think you're selecting the wrong element, your code is not returning nothing, the cell your looking at contains a `&nbsp;` which row/column are you trying to get?

Comment: yep, BIDS ASKs (share and price) sector dont have any data on the night, I want that two first rows. But if I try now the other sector that has data does not show anything either. For example class "book-viewer__trades-price"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the internet explorer rather and turn on Microsoft internet controls in vba, ive used this code and managed to pull data from the same website and paste in a cell;

sub internet()

```
Dim IEe As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc, element
    Set IEe = New InternetExplorer

    IEe.Visible = TRUE
    IEe.Navigate "https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/book/AAPL/"

       Do While IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set element = IEe.Document.getElementByID("id="ext-gen1057"") 'to get the ID, right click in internet explorer and pick the inspect element option the click on the data you want 
thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").range("a1")= element.value  

end sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I modify the IEe.Document.getElementByID("id="ext-gen1057"")  with IEe.Document.getElementByID("ext-gen1055")  , but I still get errors, in this case  "Object doesn't support this property or method" (Error 438). Any ideas? Is there any way to copy the entire table?  class="bats-table book-viewer-data-table"   Thanks !

Comment: Okay so for the error, you need to clear all instances so make sure that any point in time only one instance of the internet explorer is open, also did you check the vba references to make sure your internet controls are on?

Comment: also for the tables, use the inspect on the brower by right clicking, and when it highlights certain parts scroll your mouse to find the total highlighted part and then click, looking for an ID or name